# plot function does not plot curves just plotted legend in PyCharm

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, deep-learning, pycharm, pytorch

I am doing some homework about image classification using PyTorch. For this purpose I have visited the following link: https://github.com/Bjarten/early-stopping-pytorch/blob/master/MNIST_Early_Stopping_example.ipynb and obtained some results like this related to training losses and validation losses

```
[ 1/10] train_loss: 1.56952 valid_loss: 1.54557
Validation loss decreased (inf --> 1.545571).  Saving model ...
[ 2/10] train_loss: 1.52198 valid_loss: 1.50932
Validation loss decreased (1.545571 --> 1.509324).  Saving model ...
[ 3/10] train_loss: 1.48958 valid_loss: 1.48514
Validation loss decreased (1.509324 --> 1.485136).  Saving model ...
[ 4/10] train_loss: 1.46960 valid_loss: 1.46938
Validation loss decreased (1.485136 --> 1.469381).  Saving model ...
```

But the problem is that whenever I try to plot loss curves it does not show anything.

[my plotted figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tthbt.png)

I would expect my curve to be like [the one in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKcbH.png).
Here is the code that I used to draw this curve:

```
  # visualize the loss as the network trained
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
    plt.plot(range(1, len(train_loss) + 1), train_loss, label='Training Loss')
    plt.plot(range(1, len(valid_loss) + 1), valid_loss, label='Validation Loss')

        # find position of lowest validation loss
    minposs = valid_loss.index(min(valid_loss)) + 1
    plt.axvline(minposs, linestyle='--', color='r', label='Early Stopping Checkpoint')

    plt.xlabel('epochs')
    plt.ylabel('loss')
    plt.ylim(0, 0.5)  # consistent scale
    plt.xlim(0, len(train_loss) + 1)  # consistent scale
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.legend()
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
    fig.savefig('loss_plot.png', bbox_inches='tight')
```

Here is the value of length of the training loss and the testing loss

```
len of train loss: 1
train loss :[1.6059992909431458]
```

Comment: Can you print (and post here) the input to your `plot` function? That is `range(1, len(train_loss) + 1)` and  `train_loss`?

Comment: @Jatentaki, I have updated my post.Please have a look!

Comment: you have updated your post but not with the information I asked for. I was asking you to `print` the exact values you pass to `plt.plot` and how they are computed is (likely) irrelevant

Comment: @Jatentaki,sorry for previous updated that was not correct. here is my the results that you asked before  len of train loss: 1
train loss :[1.6059992909431458].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `len(train_loss) == 1` and `train_loss = [1.6059992909431458]`, your plot is exactly the same as if you called `plt.plot(range(1, 2), [1.6059992909431458])`, which, as you can check, is empty (this is because `plt.plot` draws lines between data points, and as there is a single data point, there can be no line drawn). You can change `plt.plot` to `plt.scatter` in order to see that single data point.

So this problem has nothing to do with plotting really, and you should rather figure out why your algorithm only runs for a single epoch and troubleshoot that, rather than plotting.